# Revert changes only on branches

Tags: git, version-control

I'm still trying to understand some git concepts. My understanding of branches is that each branch can have its own changes that will only be in that branch, then you can push and merge changes into `master`. I was being sloppy and making changes on my `master` branch (not committed), so all those changes carried through to new branches where I didn't want the changes. When I try to revert changes to the last pushed `master` branch, it is reverting these changes in all my branches. Is there a way I can revert everything in my local `master` branch and selectively revert changes to specific files in branches I already have made?

For example, lets say I have file1, and file2 in my repo. I'm happy with the latest version of repo. Then I made some changes to file1 and file2 in `master` but did not commit these changes. Then I decided I wanted to have a branch for each of these file changes so I can work on them individually, so I created new branches `file1_update` and `file2_update` from `master`. Since `master` had changes, these carried through to `file1_update` and `file2_update`. I want to revert file2 in `file1_update` and file1 in `file2_update`, and then revert everything in `master` to the latest version without any changes. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you get the answer which helps you solve the problem? If yes, you can mark the answer. And it will also benefit other members who meet similar questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: before or after reading the text below (I recommend *after*), you may also want to look at [Checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452).

What Git really does is save snapshots.  That's *almost* all there is to it:

```
$ git init          # create empty repository: no commits exist yet
```

Then, repeatedly:

```
... do some work ...
$ git add <files>   # copy the work into the index
$ git commit        # turn everything that is in the index, into a snapshot
```

Each `git commit` packages up whatever is in the *index* (aka *staging area* aka *cache*) right now and turns that into a snapshot, which is permanent—well, mostly permanent—and completely read-only.

We will come back to all of this in a bit.

#### Commits, hash IDs, and branch names

Except for the very first commit, you always make a *new* snapshot while sitting on an *existing* snapshot.  The new snapshot gets a commit hash ID—some apparently-random string of hexadecimal numbers, like `b7bd9486b055c3f967a870311e704e3bb0654e4f`.  This is the true name of the commit: it's how Git can use the commit to obtain the snapshot.  That lets you, some time in the future, find out what you saved now.

Each commit *also* records the hash ID of the commit that *was* the *existing* snapshot at the time.  If we use single uppercase letters, which as mere humans we can comprehend, instead of the big ugly hash IDs, we can call that very first snapshot `A`.  The *second* snapshot is therefore `B` and saves the actual hash ID of `A` inside it.  We say that `B` *points to* `A`:

```
A  <--B
```

When we make our third snapshot `C`, we do that while sitting on `B`, so `C` points to `B`:

```
A <-B <-C
```

What we—and Git—need to know, then, is *what's the latest snapshot?*  That's what a *branch name* is really about: a branch name, like `master`, records the *last* snapshot.  If the latest is `C`, we have:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
```

If we make a new commit `D`, the name `master` now needs to remember `D`.  `D` will point back to `C`; `master` does not need to remember `C` any more, because `D` will:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
```

The arrows within commits always point backwards, from child to parent, and since nothing—not Git itself—can change *anything* inside any existing commit, we don't really need to draw them.  But branch name arrows *do* change over time, so we should keep drawing them.

Now, suppose we make a new branch *name* like `dev` at this point.  The name `dev` will record some commit ID.  It could record any of the four, but the default is to make it using the *current* commit ID, which is the one `master` holds, giving us this:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- dev, master
```

Now that we have *two* branch names, we need to know: *which branch name are we using?*  This is where `HEAD` comes in: we attach the word HEAD to one of these names.  That's our *current branch*, whose commit ID is stored in the *branch name*, so if we are on `dev`, the picture is really:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- dev (HEAD), master
```

Now if we make a *new* commit `E`, `E` will point back to `D`, and Git will update the *current name* (`dev`) to point to `E`:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
          \
           E   <-- dev (HEAD)
```

If we now run `git checkout master` and make a new commit `F`, `F` will point back, not to `E`, but to `D`—that's the one `master` points to—and Git will update `master` to point to `F`:

```
A--B--C--D--F   <-- master (HEAD)
          \
           E   <-- dev
```

That's it: that's all that a branch name is and does!  It just records the *latest* commit, which Git calls the *tip commit*.  The good stuff is all in the commits: each commit is a complete snapshot of everything that was in the index.

#### The index and the work-tree

All the files that are *inside* a commit are in a special, Git-only, compressed form (often highly compressed, at least for source text files).  Git is pretty much the only program that can read them or do anything with them.<sup>1</sup>  So Git needs a way that you and your computer can read and write to ordinary-format files.  Those files go into your *work-tree*, so-called because here, you can work with them.

Git has, however, an intermediate form for all the files.  It takes those compressed, Git-only, read-only files and copies them—well, stuff *about* them, really—into something Git calls the *index*.  Here, the files are still compressed in a Git-only form, but here, they *can* be overwritten.  It also uses this index to keep track of—to *index* and *cache*, hence those names—information about the work-tree files.  This is where Git gets most of its speed.  There are similar VCSes that don't have an index, proving that it's unnecessary in a theoretical sense, but they are slower (sometimes hugely slower) than Git.

Having provided this index, Git forces you to *use* the index, even if you don't really want to.  Instead of copying files straight from a commit to the work-tree, it copies files from the commit, into the index first, and only *then* expands them out to normal form in the work-tree.  This is why Git makes you run `git add` every time: what `git add` does is to copy the file *from* the work-tree, *into* the index (compressing it into Git format in the process).

This is how it is that `git commit` is so fast, compared to other VCSes: Git can just take whatever is in the index right now, package it into a commit, and be done.  All the hard work of compressing files is already done!  Git does not even have to look at the work-tree.

This also means that after `git commit`, the *new* commit you just made, matches the index.  Hence, after `git checkout branch`, the index matches the tip commit of *`branch`*, because Git copied the commit to the index while updating the work-tree.  After `git commit` changes *`branch`* to have a new tip commit, the index matches the (new) tip commit of *`branch`*, because Git copied the index—froze it into a snapshot—to make the commit.

---

<sup>1</sup>Nothing can change them: this is a design feature; the actual contents of everything are stored under a crytpographic checksum hash ID.  (This is where the hash IDs actually come from.  The hash ID is exquisitely sensitive to every single bit, so if you were to change something—accidentally, like a disk error, or on purpose by overwriting it—Git would detect that the object's checksum no longer matches the checksum-key used to *retrieve* the object.  That's *why* everything, once committed, is read-only.

Commits *can* be forgotten about, on purpose.  Doing so is sometimes tricky, and they will very easily get *restored:* Git is mainly designed to add things, not to remove them, and is much more willing to add new things than it is to forget old ones.  We won't cover this in any detail here.

---

#### "But commits look like diffs!"

If you run:

```
git show <commit>
```

or:

```
git log -p
```

you will see each commit shown as a patch.  Git can do this *because* each commit stores its *previous* commit—its *parent*—inside the commit.  Git simply extracts both snapshots and compares them.  Whatever is different, gets shown.

(There is a complication here at merge commits, but we'll just ignore that, too.)

#### Revert

What revert does can now be described very simply:<sup>2</sup> Git turns the commit into a patch, then *reverse applies* the patch to some other commit.

That is, if the commit-as-patch says "add a line to file A", Git *removes* that line from that file.  If the commit-as-patch says "remove a line from file B", Git *adds* that line to that file.

Having reverse-applied the commit to the current commit (through the work-tree and using the index that matches the current commit), Git copies the updated files into the index as if by `git add`, then makes a new commit, automatically supplying the commit log message.  You can override some of these with various flags, and there are complications (see footnote 2) when the patch doesn't apply properly.  But that's mostly it.

---

<sup>2</sup>This is actually too simple.  Revert really invokes Git's three-way merge machinery (as does `git cherry-pick`).  In simple, unconflicted cases, however, "apply a patch and commit" (cherry-pick) or "reverse-apply a patch and commit" (revert) suffice to describe the process.

---

#### Revert is a poor name for this process

Mercurial (which is otherwise a lot like Git, only slower and more user-friendly) calls this `hg backout` rather than `hg revert`, because it *backs out* the changes of a commit.  The verb [*revert*](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/revert), often with the auxiliary word *to* as in *revert to*, means—at least to some people—to change the entire contents back.  That is, instead of saying:

> "commit a123456 changed one line of file README.txt and I want that one *line* changed back"

people sometimes mean:

> "README.txt has been changed a lot since commit a123456, and I want *the version that was in a123456 back*, so that means I want _____"

and they fill in the blank with "to revert README.txt to a123456" and thus they reach for `git revert`.

That's not what `git revert` does.  To *do* that, one needs to extract the file `README.txt` *from* commit `a123456`.  Confusingly, the main Git command that does this is `git checkout`, using a different syntax from `git checkout branch`.  (It *should* have been a separate command, and in Mercurial it is: it is `hg revert`!)  If you want this in Git, you can write:

```
git checkout a123456 -- README.txt
```

which copies `README.txt` from commit `a123456` into the index (as usual), then expands it into normal, not-Git-only, format into your work-tree as file `README.txt`.

Note that in all modern versions of Git, you can also use:

```
git show a123456:README.txt
```

which displays the contents of that file, as of that commit, on your screen, and generally works with redirection, so that you can save it to a file inside or outside of your work-tree:

```
git show a123456:README.txt > restored-readme
```

for instance.  This *does not* affect the index.

Answer (score 0):

You can't `revert` if you haven't `committed` the changes, you might want to `git stash` some files, then `git add` the files you want and then `git commit` with the added files.

Then switch branches using `git checkout mybranch` and then use `git stash pop` to add back the stashed files.

**EDIT WITH EXAMPLE**

Let's say I'm on the branch master, and I modify file1 + file2 without committing.
Then I switch to branch toto (`git checkout -b toto`), file1 + file2 changes will be visible in the branch toto BUT I want only file1 changes on this branch.

Well, I git stash file2 (which will 'reset' the file2 file) then I `git add file1` then `git commit -m "yeahhhh"`.

After that, I go back to master branch, and `git stash pop` so I have my file2 modifications back.

Comment: But I think I can `revert` specific files in the branch and keep the changes in the files I actually want changes to. Would that not be the same?

Comment: ``git revert`` is a specific command to revert - sic - committed files. Since you have not committed any file (that's what you are saying in your post), this command won't be helpful in this case.

Comment: Maybe I didn't phrase it perfectly or am misunderstanding something in git. The latest committed changes to `master` are what I want to revert some of the files to

Comment: @greenthumbtack So are the files committed or nah?

Answer (score 0):

Your misunderstanding ist that you do *not* make changes in a "branch". You make changes to the *current state* of the files on your hard disk. `git` does not relate this changes to a branch until you check them in.

Comment: What is the purpose of a branch then? I thought I could essentially have different versional of the same file in a repo but switching between branches. That's probably a bigger question than just for this comment and question though

Comment: @greenthumbtack For this to be true, you have to ``git commit`` the file in the branch, then when you switch branch, you will have different commits that change the file in different ways.